# While running npm run test,SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 error I receive

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, orm, sequelize.js

This is my config.json file:

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "xyz",
    "password": "password123",
    "database": "db1",
    "host": "localhost",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_production",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
}
```

This is my app.js file

```
  const useit = async () => {
    await sequelize.authenticate();
}
//Listening 
app.listen({ port: 8000 }, async () => {
  console.log('Server up on http://localhost:8000')
  useit();
  console.log('Database Connected!')
  await sequelize.sync({alter:true});
  
})

module.exports = app;
```

In ORM I have use Sequalize along with postgres as my backend.Everything works fine,all my REST API endpoints works fine,however,when i run npm run test this is the error I recieve:

```
 console.warn
    failed to find WebSocket

      at $.send (eval at oo_cm (app.js:386:57), <anonymous>:1:5120)

  console.warn
    failed to find WebSocket

      at $.send (eval at oo_cm (app.js:386:57), <anonymous>:1:5120)

 FAIL  test/app.test.js
  ✕ GET random not found endpoint (33 ms)

  ● GET random not found endpoint

    SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

      at Client._connectionCallback (node_modules/sequelize/src/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:179:24)
      at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:316:19)
      at Client._handleErrorEvent (node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:326:19)
      at Socket.reportStreamError (node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:57:12)

  ● GET random not found endpoint

    SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

      at Client._connectionCallback (node_modules/sequelize/src/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:179:24)
      at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:316:19)
      at Client._handleErrorEvent (node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:326:19)
      at Socket.reportStreamError (node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:57:12)
```

I dont know whats the issue with the whole code.Tried to change stuff inside config file and app.js but nothing works.My test cases always fails with the same error.Plz help me out.

Comment: Are you using Postgres, or MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

3306 is the port number for MySQL. However, you seem to be connecting using the PostgreSQL driver.

- Check your database connection configuration. Either run MySQL or PostgreSQL, and check that your config is correct.
- Are you using the correct configuration from the config file? Also, is the environment variable NODE_ENV correctly set? (development)
- Are the DB services running?